# Selenium Chromedriver not working from Google Cloud Server

Tags: python-3.x, linux, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to program a web scraping python script from a basic Google cloud server.  I have succesfully downloaded selenium and chromedriver onto the VM.  When I run my code i return this error

My python code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/owner/Desktop/chromedriver')
URL = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news'

driver.get(URL)

driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait for seconds

uiOuter = driver.find_element_by_id('ui-outer')

aHref = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.flexposts__story-title a')

span = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.flexposts__storydisplay-info')

headline = open("headlines.txt","w+")

for x in aHref:
    for y in span:
        headline.write(x.text + "\n" + y.text + "\n" + "\n")
```

The Error message is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

Im not sure exactly what this means and of course not sure what to do to fix it.  All help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.